# Configuring PhpStorm 2016.1 with PhalconPHP 2.1

Tags: php, phpstorm, phalcon

I have installed PhpStorm 2016.1 and configured it to use the Phalcon Devtools for Phalcon 2.1.0 RC1 also I configured the PHP language level to PHP 7 with the interpreter to PHP 7.0.5 (I have that version installed), I can run commands using the "Run-Command" option in PhpStorm and tested the Phalcon Dev-tools commands from there and they work perfectly, the only problem I'm having is that the IDE doesn't recognize Phalcon code, eg.

```
<?php
class ClientController extends Phalcon\MVC\Controller
```

The IDE shows the following message:

```
Undefined class Controller
```

Like it does not recognize the Phalcon PHP code methods and classes, when I run my code in the browser it works perfectly, so I have everything installed correctly (Phalcon + PHP 7.0.5), I'm using Ubuntu 15.04

Do I need to do something else? Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You are sure that you enabled phalcon for non-cli php sapi?

Comment: And... i recommend to use NetBeans IDE :) its free, opensource and from my experience- works better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside PhpStorm, open your project view ( View > Tool Windows > Project ).
At the bottom of your project files you'll have the item "External Libraries".

Open it and browse to the location where you have stored your IDE files for Phalcon 2.1.0 ("/your/directory/phalcon-devtools-master/ide/2.1.0")

Add and apply the changes and you should have IDE support now.

Comment: It works now, but is weird I did this exact step but using the phpstorm folder, but it didn't work, I changed it to ide/2.1.0 and it works perfectly, thank you very much!